# Maven Failsafe plugin cannot find class

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

The project where I'm working on has several modules and one of the modules is `integration_test`, integrations test for all the others modules. This is a weird architecture for me and I'm not sure if I'm handling this situation correctly.

We haven't continous integration, right now we are running the suite test from Eclipse but we want to run it from a continuos integration server. I have been working on update our POM to execute it from the command line. I will include a sample project below because paste here the classes I think is not enough.

I followed the Maven Failsafe plugin documentation, but when I execute `mvn clean verify -P integration-test` I get `Cannot find class in classpath: TestApiMain`

I think this is because is trying to running that class before it's compiled but I don't know how to run the integration test after all other modules are actually compiled. I also want to implement Jacoco for test coverage. Reading the following guide to implement Jacoco I think I'm close:

https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/

Exception when execute `mvn clean verify -P integration-test`:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.20.1:verify (integration-test) on project root: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/francisco_aguiar/repos/sample_project/target/failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: TestApiMain
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:673)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:535)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:280)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1124)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:954)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:832)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Sample_project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ow--OYz4LzxNZvoBPtb5Ub2khXSR74w3/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined plugin `failsafe` in parent pom in `build/plugins` section. It means every module, including parent, in phase `integration-test` must call `failsafe(TestApiMain.class)`.

It will not work, because `TestApiMain` is defined in last module `integration_test`

You should move `failsafe` definition to `integration_test/pom.xml` to section `build/plugins`

Comment: Dammit, so obvious. But now is ignoring my suiteXmlFile and the tests fails this way.

Comment: And I need to execute that file, the tests are in a framework that setup the environment and standalone seems is not working... But that is another problem...

Comment: Actually it doesn't work, I tried with the sample project and I'm getting the same error `Cannot find class in classpath: TestApiMain`

Comment: @FranAguiar, which module fails? I downloaded your sample project and it pass integration test after modification

Comment: Yes, my bad, it works. I was trying with a different sample... If works with the sample project it should work with the real.
Now I see what is going on, it's executing the standalone test and the suite file. I only what the suite

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who reads this who has teh project configured correctly but still has a classes not found then see if the following applies.

When upgrading to 3.0.0-M5 this plugin can fail to find classes from a transitive dependency. One simple fix instead of rolling back to 3.0.0-M4 is to add classesDirectory to your plugin configuration

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Comment: it works...but why?!